# In Slate.js editor.apply(operation) is not applying "split_node" operations correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, slate, slatejs

I am designing a google-doc like collaborative tool with latest React + Slate as Frontend and Flask in Backend. I am using socket-io in React and flask_socketio in Python to emit and listen content from other collaborators.
React app code:

```
const RichTextExample = props => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(props.currentEditor);
  const editor = useMemo(() => withHistory(withReact(createEditor())), []);
  const id = useRef(`${Date.now()}`);
  const remote = useRef(false);
  const socketchange = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("new-remote-operations", ({ editorId, ops, doc_id }) => {
      if (id.current !== editorId && doc_id === props.document.doc_id) {
        remote.current = true;
        JSON.parse(ops).forEach(op => {
          console.log("LISTEN: applying op", op);
          editor.apply(op);
        });
        remote.current = false;
        console.log('value is ', value);
        socketchange.current = true; //variable to track socket changes in editor via operations
      }
    });}, [])
    return(
    <Slate
        editor={editor}
        value={value}
        onChange={value => {
          setValue(value);
          const ops = editor.operations
          .filter(o => {
            if (o) {
              return o.type !== "set_selection" && o.type !== "set_value";
            }
            return false;
          });
          if (ops.length && !remote.current && !socketchange.current) {
            console.log("EMIT: Editor operations are ", ops);
            socket.emit("new-operations", {
              editorId: id.current,
              ops: JSON.stringify(ops),
              doc_id: props.document.doc_id
            });
          }
          socketchange.current = false;
        }}
      >
```

Python code for socket is simple:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
db_name = 'userdoc.db'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret-key'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///'+db_name
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")
@socketio.on('new-operations', namespace='/')
def operations(data):
    print('operations listened...1/2/3..')
    emit('new-remote-operations', data, broadcast=True, include_self=False)
```

> **Issue**:
>
> When split_node is passed as an type of operation in socket.on(),
> editor.apply(op) doesn't apply it as it suppose to. Please help me on this.

Because of this, I get following two cases:
[image: Case 1]

[image]
[image]

Comment: For future reference: https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate/issues/3493 (I have raised an issue on Slate repo). If anyone things this is not a bug, please help me understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the issue you are facing is because you send a batch of operations that should not be applied one by one.

A `split_node` operation like the one you are generating by hitting `enter` will actually split all the nested nodes till it reaches the leaves, and move some nodes around.

Concretely, a split_node is actually 2-3 operations following each others, that can't be applied solely. If you apply the first one for example, that would split the text node, and end up with two `Text` sharing the same attributes. Slate will normalize them and re-merge them as soon as it can, which in your case, happen between each `editor.apply(op)`.

I think the solution here, is simply to wrap your whole loop inside the `withoutNormalizing` method. It will prevent Slate to normalize the document in-between the operations.

#### For Slate <= 0.47

```js
editor.withoutNormalizing(() => {
  JSON.parse(ops).forEach(op => {
    editor.apply(op);
  });
})
```

#### For Slate >= 0.5

```js
Editor.withoutNormalizing(editor, () => {
  JSON.parse(ops).forEach(op => {
    editor.apply(op);
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Please provide some links to better understand slate >=0.5.